# Should I use Fn, FnMut and FnOnce only for closures?

Tags: rust, functional-programming, closures

Scenario: I want to write an optimiser algorithm which takes a univariate function as an argument. I want it to work both with closures and structs implementing some method to calculate the value of the optimised function. Should I declare my optimiser as taking an `FnMut` argument or some other trait which would be implemented by any struct I want to pass to the optimiser?

Comment: That has nothing to do with how many arguments the function takes but in what way the function may capture its environment. `Fn`s capture their environment by shared reference or not at all (which makes every `fn` a `Fn`), `FnMut`s may capture their environment by mutable reference, and `FnOnce`s may move values out of their environment and into the closure. Besides that, don't take closures by reference, take them by value. References to a closure will automatically implement the closure's trait.

Comment: That's now what I wanted to ask for, but I see that I need to phrase my question more clearly. I'll try to rephrase it.

Comment: Hope this is clearer...

Comment: You can't (yet) implement the Fn traits yourself on stable Rust ([tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29625)). You should probably define your own trait that does the computation which you can then implement for your structs and for any type that implements `Fn` (or `FnMut`).

Comment: I see, thanks. That clears it up. How do I implement a trait X for any type which implements trait Y?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't ([yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29625)) implement the Fn traits yourself on stable Rust. You should probably define your own trait that does the computation which you can then implement for your structs and for any type that implements Fn (or FnMut):

```
// I'm opting for `&mut self` here as it's more general
// but this might not be necessary for your use case
trait Calculate<T, U> {
    fn calculate(&mut self, t: T) -> U;
}

// Because `Fn: FnMut` this will also implement `Calculate` for `Fn`.
impl<F, T, U> Calculate<T, U> for F
where F: FnMut(T) -> U {
    fn calculate(&mut self, t: T) -> U {
        (self)(t)
    }
}

struct State {
    flag: bool,
}
impl<T, U> Calculate<T, U> for State
where T: Into<U> {
    fn calculate(&mut self, t: T) -> U {
        self.flag = true;
        // or whatever calculation you actually need to do here
        t.into()
    }
}
```